# BCrypt algorithm: Is it good to return hashed password from database for comparision?

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I am using BCrypt algorithm in ASP.NET MVC project as mentioned following:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/475262/UseplusBCryptplustoplusHashplusYourplusPasswords

As I am using N Tier architecture, need to create method in data access layer which returns hashed password from database. At this point, I am not comfortable.

Is it good to return hashed password from database? I want to do it from database side but for checking password, I need to call following method and for this, I need to have hashed password:

BCrypt.CheckPassword(myPassword, myHash);

Is there any other way to do it? What is the best way to implement it?

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you're uncomfortable with returning a hash from the DB to your BLL/DAL??

Comment: Because there is no need of salt in this algo for comparision, so any one compare the hashed password with guessed password(using check password)...that's why

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's fine to pull the hashed value from the database, and in fact is required unless you were to implement a custom function in the database. Just don't check the password on the client, check it server side.

Comment: Actually there are different clients for same DB and each one has their own algo, so I need to implement method in service layer to return hashed password (I can't implement comparison in service layer). As there is no need of salt in this algo for comparision, so any one compare the hashed password with guessed password(using check password)...that's why

Comment: There is a salt with bcrypt. It's stored at the beginning of the value.

Comment: @WebWorld what does the lack of a password salt determine where in your layered approach the hashed(raw text password) == hashedPassword matter?  I feel like either we or you are missing something :P

Comment: In the link, salt is not used for comparision..Is it wrong?

Comment: @WebWorld my comments have nothing to do with password salts, you keep bringing it up as the lack of one being a determining factor of where you place your "password checking" logic when it comes to what layer. I'm trying to understand why it keeps being brought up in case we're missing something in our responses

Comment: @WebWorld the salt and work rounds value are used to re-create the hash using the plaintext value before comparing it to the hash value.

Answer (score 0):

*The bcrypt salt/hash is **not** a secret*<sup>1</sup> - the idea is that even if this is "exposed" it will be unfeasible to reverse. There might be an *additional* secret key used with HMAC, eg., but that is external to a base bcrypt hash.

It is customary in many applications to keep the authentication/hash verification check into the relevant application/service layers - as shown - but it could also be done in the database (e.g. with a sproc, depending). But just use the sample code provided; it is sufficient.

There must be trust in the service that says, "yes, this is a valid pass-phrase representing the hash". Feeding it a known/compromised hash value could cause it to lie - but at that point the entire system is compromised and is no different than having the database, acting as an external provider, say "I trust this user".

---

<sup>1</sup> While a proper password hash is not a secret and it provides security through resistance to being reversed, hashes should generally be kept confidential. Generally, only the service using the hash for authentication should have a need to access the hash, and should only access the hash by known key. This is just good house-keeping.

Comment: Do you recommend any other algorithm for the best security?

Comment: @WebWorld bcrypt or scrypt are the only password hash algorithms I accept as valid these days (some would argue PBKDF2 is still relevant). However, my ultimately recommendation is to "let someone else handle the authentications" (e.g. a framework, vetted library, or external authentication provider).